# Is it safe to implement GetHashCode by returning an unique ID from the object?

Tags: gethashcode

Let's say I have a POCO that represents a database row. I have access to the ID of that row.

Is it safe to implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` by leveraging that unique ID ?

```
public class Project
{
    public string ID { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var pr = obj as Project;
        if (pr == null) return false;
        if (pr.ID == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempt to .Equals an entity with null ID");
        return pr.ID == ID;
    }
        
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (ID == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempt to .GetHashCode on an entity with null ID");
        return ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I believe this could work because

- ID is not mutable
- I handle the case where ID is null

Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: Common pattern for entity objects and such. No problem whatsoever.

Comment: ID is a unique key for every row? No NULL entries allowed? Then I see no problem.

Comment: @SQLPolice yes, I'm taking the ID straight from the table, so as long as the RDBMS isn't corrupted / playing jokes, the ID should be unique.